# How to determine number of structural isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

I have come across many questions where I'm asked to give the number of possible structural isomers. For example number, [structural isomers of hexane](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1997-12/878572346.Ch.r.html) is 5, while the number structural isomers of decane is 75.

How can I determine the possible number of structural isomers of a given organic compound?

Comment: Is this for a specific class of organic molecule or any organic molecule? Because the numbers you gave suggest that the number of isomers quickly increases with size of molecule, and that's just for simple hydrocarbons. And do stereoisomers count? I tried to come up with an equation for simple hydrocarbons, but couldn't identify 5 isomers for hexane, it's too late at night.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is generally no simple, formulaic way to do this w/r/t molecules of arbitrary complexity and/or size. Various computational approaches exist; search for, e.g., isomer enumeration.

Comment: @user137 This is not for stereo isomer. It is just for simple hydrocarbons. [five structural isomers of hexane](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1997-12/878572346.Ch.r.html)

Comment: See [this](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_formula_to_find_how_many_structural_isomers_alkane_have).

Comment: @ashu This only gives you the degree of unsaturation, which is for alkanes always zero.

Comment: @Martin Do you consider cyclic alkanes here? they would have a 1.

Comment: @user137 I would consider only n-alkanes that obey $\ce{C_{n}H_{2n+2}}$. You are of course correct for cycloalkanes.

Comment: If you are given a question like this, I think the purpose is to get you to start drawing different structures and realize which ones are equivalent to ones you have already drawn.

Comment: @jerepierre You are right, my teacher told me same thing but sometimes it becomes dead end job like for example decane.

Comment: I like that the [On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) has a sequence with [the number of structural isomers for alkanes with $n$ carbon atoms](https://oeis.org/A000602). The references therein may prove useful in your search for techniques to quantify possible isomers for a given formula.

Comment: [Good Will Hunting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570240/proof-involving-a-problem-from-good-will-hunting) [might know](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_03/goodwill/).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**It isn't easy but it is an interesting research topic**

Determining the number of possible structures for a given range of chemical formulae isn't simple even for saturated hydrocarbons. The number of possible structural isomers rises rapidly with the number of carbons and soon exceeds your ability to enumerate or identify the options by hand. [Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_straight-chain_alkanes), for example, lists the numbers of isomers and stereoisomers for molecules with up to 120 carbons. But the counts are getting silly even at 10 carbons where there are 75 isomers and 136 stereoisomers.

It has been an interesting research topic in computational chemistry and mathematics. [This old paper (pdf),](http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2004/040960.pdf) for example, list some formulae for simple hydrocarbons among other simple series. Part of the interest arises because of the relationship to the mathematics of graph theory (it seems that chemistry has inspired some new ideas in this field of mathematics partially because enumerating possible isomers of hydrocarbons is strongly related to drawing certain simple trees which is intuitively obvious if you use the standard chemical convention of drawing just the carbon backbone and ignoring hydrogens).

You can look up the answers on the fascinating mathematics site OEIS (the online encyclopaedia of integer sequences). The sequence for simple hydrocarbons is [here](http://oeis.org/A000602).

But the mathematical approach oversimplifies things from the point of view of real-world chemistry. Mathematical trees are idealised abstract objects that ignore real-world chemical constraints like the fact that atoms take up *space* in three dimensions. This means that some structures that can be drawn cannot exist in the real world because the atoms are too crowded and cannot physically exist without enough strain to cause them to fall apart.

Luckily, computation chemists have also studied this. There is, unfortunately, no obvious shortcut other than trying to create models of the possible structures and testing them to see if they are too strained to exist. The first two isomers that are too crowded are for 16 and 17 carbons and have these structures:

[image: the first "impossible" hydrocarbons]

If you have any intuition of the space filling view of these, you should be able to see why they are problematic. A research group at Cambridge University has produced an applet to enumerate the physically possible isomers for a given number of carbons which is available [here](http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/data/isomercount/) if your Java settings allow it. The results are discussed in a paper available in the [Journal of Chemical Information and Modelling](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci0497657).

Comment: I've ran regression for these wiki data and for long chains number of isomers rises exponentially and it's about 0.001e^x, where x is no of C atoms.

Comment: "But the counts are getting silly even at 10 carbons where there are **75 isomers** and 136 stereoisomers." By 75 isomers , you mean constitutional isomers right?

Answer (score 27):

(1) As for the number of alkanes ($\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$),  Table 1, which is extracted from the data reported in 

[S. Fujita, *MATCH Commun. Math. Comput. Chem.*, **57**, 
299--340 (2007)](http://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match57/n2/match57n2_299-340.pdf) (access free), 
shows the comparison between two enumerations based on 
Polya's theorem and on Fujita's proligand method.

[image]

The number of alkanes ($\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$) 
as constitutional isomers (structural isomers) and as steric isomers 
is calculated by Polya's theorem (G. Polya and R. C. Read, 

[Combinatorial Enumeration of Groups, Graphs, and Chemical Compounds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4664-0/page/1), Springer (1987)). 
In the process of calculating constitutional isomers, 
one 2D structure (graph or constitution) is counted just once. 
In the process of calculating steric isomers, one achiral molecule or each chiral molecule 
of an enantiomeric pair is counted just once, where achiral molecules and chiral molecules 
are not differentiated from each other.

On the other hand, 
the number of alkanes ($\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$) 
as three-dimensional (3D) structural isomers 
and as steric isomers is 
calculated by Fujita's proligand method 
(S. Fujita, 

[Combinatorial Enumeration of Graphs, Tree-Dimensional Structures, and 
Chemical Compounds](http://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/mcm15.html), Unversity of Kragujevac (2013)). 
In the process of calculating 3D structural isomers, 
one achiral molecule or one pair of enantiomers is counted just once, 
where achiral molecules and chiral molecules (enantiomeric pairs) 
are differentiated from each other.

For more information, see an account article entitled 
"Numbers of Alkanes and Monosubstituted Alkanes. 
A Long-Standing Interdisciplinary Problem over 130 Years" 
(
[S. Fujita,  *Bull. Chem. Soc. Japan*, **83**, 1--18 (2010)](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bcsj/83/1/83_20090008/_pdf), 
access free). This account article has discussed the difference between graph enumeration (Polya's theorem) and 3D structural enmeration (Fujita's proligand method) during recursive calculation.

It should be emphasized that graph-theoretical enumerations of chemical compounds 
as constitutional isomers (structural isomers) and as steric isomers (based on asymmetry) 
should be differentiated from stereochemical enumerations of chemical compounds 
as 3D structural isomers and as steric isomers (based on chirality). 
Although steric isomers based on asymmetry (graphs governed by permutation groups) and 
steric isomers based on chirality (3D structures governed by point groups) give identical 
enumeration results, they are conceptually different entities. 
This point of view stems from Fujita's stereoisogram approach, 
which is described in a recent book 
(S. Fujita 
[Mathematical Stereochemistry](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/431387), De Gruyter (2015)).

(2) Enumeration of achiral and chiral alkanes of a given carbon content has been 
conducted by considering internal branching 
(
[S. Fujita, *Bull. Chem. Soc. Jpn.*, **81**, 1423--1453 (2008)](http://doi.org/10.1246/bcsj.81.1423)). 
Figure 3 of this report is cited below.

[image]

The symbol [q, t, s, p] means 
the presence of q quaternary carbons, t tertiary carbons, s secondary carbons, 
and p primary carbons. Alkanes are categorized into 
centroidal and bicentroidal alkanes, which are the 3D extension of 
centroidal and bicentroidal trees of graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is a start towards a partial answer, but I tried to count the isomers of methane through nonane, and only by moving methyl groups around, each "branch" is only 1 CH3. I noticed a pattern in the number of 1 branch, 2 branch, 3 branch, and 4 branch isomers. Don't know how accurate these numbers are or how well this pattern holds up.

```
N   Straight    1 Branch    2 Branch    3 Branch    4 Branch
1          1           0           0           0           0
2          1           0           0           0           0
3          1           0           0           0           0
4          1           1           0           0           0
5          1           1           1           0           0
6          1           2           2           0           0
7          1           2           4           0           0
8          1           3           6           1           1
9          1           3           9           4           3
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no straight up formula. Obviously there are very general trends, but not precise enough to tell you the number of isomers.

If you need to decide how many isomers something has, I suggest you either do it manually or use a programme like this: http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/tools/isomercount/

Answer (score -3):

We can calculate the number of structural isomers by double bond equivalent i.e by using the formula:

$$1+ \sum_i \frac{n_i (v_i - 2)}{2} $$

where $n$ repesents the number of atoms $i$ of a given valency, and $v_i$ represents these atoms’ valency. Example:

$$\ce{C4H6}: 1+ \sum_i \frac{n_i (v_i - 2)}{2}  = 1+ \frac{4(4-2)}{2}+\frac{6(1-2)}{2}  \\
= \frac{8-6}{2} +1 = 2 $$
Thus the compound may contain two double bonds or a triple bond and there are two possible isomers.

Comment: The question pertains towards alkanes and the formula that you have specified will be helpful (to a small extent) only for cyclic alkanes. This might as well be a comment than an answer. And Welocme to Chem.SE!

Comment: This answer is *blatantly* wrong. It calculates the double bond equivalents *but* the example used ($\ce{C4H6}$; i.e. butadiene, cyclobutene or butyne) already has five possible isomers if only a straight chain is assumed. $5 \ne 2$.